# Multiple file download using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the javascript to download multiple file from url.

I have used the following url to do this but not find any solutions,

Its working fine for firefox and google chrome but not work with ie and edge

I have used the following code.

```
reportFileList.forEach((report, index) => {
    var downloadUrl = report
    setTimeout(function() {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.target = '_parent';
        if ('download' in a) {
            a.download = downloadUrl;
        }

        (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
        if (a.click) {
            a.click(); // The click method is supported by most browsers.
        } 
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your browsers **developer** tools console?

Comment: no i dont get any error it just download the last files

Comment: Its working fine for firefox and google chrome but not work with ie and edge

Comment: right, that sort of information would probably be useful **in the question** - the fact that microsoft browsers don't work like other browsers is very surprising and rare

Comment: why not create a zip of it then dl it?

Comment: but i need it in this way. have any other alternate for this ?

Comment: and the file is download from the url so what is the best for that ?

Comment: did you tried using `window.open`?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Yes i have try that

Comment: As I understand it, you're programmatically creating link elements, clicking on them and then deleting them to load their pages. This is a long-winded way of doing things. Also, I don't see the point, since you can only have one page loaded at a time. What are you trying to achieve? "no i dont get any error it just download the last files" If you're saying that only one page loads, that makes complete sense: The browser knows that loading more than one page at once is silly, so it cancels all but the last load. Maybe you wanted different `setTimeout` intervals for the different pages?

Comment: And judging by your answer, it looks like you were indeed trying to load the pages at different times. You could have achieved more or less the same thing by changing `500` to `500 * index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with following code-->
Maybe it helps somebody.

```
function download_files(files) {
function download_next(i) {
 if (i >= files.length) {
   return;
 }
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = files[i].download;
 a.target = '_blank';

 if ('download' in a) {
   a.download = files[i].download;
 }

 (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
 if (a.click) {
   a.click(); // The click method is supported by most browsers.
 }
 else {
    window.open(files[i].download);
 }
 console.log('1');
 a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
 setTimeout(function() {
   download_next(i + 1);
 }, 5000);
}
// Initiate the first download.
download_next(0);
}

function do_dl() {
 download_files([
   { download: "https://www.example.com"},
   { download: "https://www.example.com"},
   { download: "https://www.example.com"},
   { download: "https://www.example.com"},
 ]);
};


do_dl();
```

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code works (tested in Chrome) the problem must be somewhere else:

- Maybe the reportFileList var is malformed.
- Some browsers prompt you to make multiple downloads, it must be enabled.

Example: http://js.do/code/161479

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="line-height: 18px; font-size: 18px;  font-family: times;">
Click "<i>Load samples</i>" to view and edit more JS samples.<br>

<script>
var reportFileList = ['https://www.example.com','https://www.example.com','https://www.example.com'];
reportFileList.forEach((report, index) => {
            var downloadUrl = report
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.target = '_parent';
                    if ('download' in a) {
                        a.download = downloadUrl;
                    }

                    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
                    if (a.click) {
                        a.click(); // The click method is supported by most browsers.
                    } 
                    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
                }, 500);



    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes its working fine on chrome, have u check my question clearly ?

Comment: I have read your question clearly, the problem is that you edited the question to include those details later: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45143177/revisions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A fix that worked for me was to change target of `a` tag to `_blank` target and allow in browser for **Popups** permissions.